# How to understand the preposition "with"? What does the phrase "with young people" modify?

Tags: prepositions

> A new TV series in England, *Away from it all*, has surprised everyone
>   by becoming a huge success ***with*** young people across the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing it like this might help,

> (A new TV series in England, Away from it all,) has surprised everyone by becoming (a huge success) with (young people across the country).

```
NOTE: It could be (and perhaps should be) nested, but nested parentheses can be confusing.
```

The sentence roughly means "the series has surprised everyone by becoming a huge success".

But what kind of success?

It's the success with young people (across the country).

Comment: Yes, "with young people" modifies "a success". But can you use some simple words to describe the meaning of "with "here? Cuz There is no appropriate explantion to explain this preposition in this sentence.

Comment: @user48070 Let's move our discussion to http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/57787/3281, because *with* in the two questions are used in basically the same way.