# How to understand the preposition "with"?

Tags: prepositions

> She is popular **with** the young people.

Why use *"with"* here?

How should I understand the preposition *"with"* in this context?

Comment: This should be a good starting point: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/with, sense 5.

Comment: Do you mean the following:used for saying what causes someone or something to be in a particular state.
e.g.:The children were already weak with exhaustion.
The air was thick with smoke.

Comment: Can I say " she is popular among young people"?

Comment: I rechecked sense 5 once again, and I don't think it really fits. Sorry about that. (The definition seems to suggest a bit different sense of *with*. Prepositions of English are usually like this. They're very flexible and it's usually not a good idea to explain it with a rigid definition.) As for "be popular among", you definitely can. (And so as *with*.)

Comment: (con't) Though sense 5 does not really entirely miss the point, imho. Oxford Dictionaries defines *with* in the same sense [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/with) as sense 7: "In relation to", which is vague enough to cover a wide range of the usage of *with*.

Comment: In another dictionary: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with, sense 2. Particularly, 2e: "over, on" <no longer has any influence with them>.

Comment: Actually,What I want to know is how the native speaker understand the preposition  in the sentences correctly. There must be some ways for you to understandthem correctly directly.

Comment: *She is popular among young people* is fine. It means the same as *She is popular with young people.* (Note: not 'the young people'.)

Comment: [Oxford dictionary definition 7](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/with?q=With+)

Comment: I think we're on shaky ground referring people to dictionaries for the "meaning" of prepositions. None of the dictionaries linked in these comments is at all helpful in this case; none of them suggests anything like OP's *among*, which is exactly what is wanted.

Answer (score 3):

If you look up the preposition "with" in a dictionary, you will find that it's used in different senses. Amongst them,  it also means "concerning, regarding, or in connection with". For example, "she's angry with me". We usually use this preposition in this sense with the adjective popular.  However, we can also use "among" instead of "with" with popular.

Comment: I agree: prepositions can only be understood in context. With can mean a lot of different things, at least translated into German. It is often easier to learn and translate verb+preposition or adjective+preposition.

Answer (score 0):

The English preposition with has some uses which for non-native learners are a bit astonishing as they are different from the basic meaning of "with".

The basic meaning of with is indicating the instrument as in

> 1. I could open the door with my key.

But "with" can indicate other things, eg cause/ why?

> 2. The children jumped with joy.

"with" + person/s can be a where-indication.

> 3. I left the key with my neighbour/with the Smiths.

"with" is a preposition that learners should study in a larger dictionary and see which uses of "with" are normal for them and which uses are different from the use in their mother tongue.

The entry with in Longman's DCE has 23 numbers.
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/with
In number 15 and 16 "with" is used as a where-indication. (This use should have more examples.)